# non-numeric argument to binary operator with nls

Tags: r, regression, non-linear-regression, nls

I'd like to fit a non-linear model using `nls`, but I'm getting a `non-numeric argument to binary operator` error:

```
df <- data.frame(task=rep(c("x", "y", "z"), each=6), time=rep(c(1:18)), y=c(1, 5, 9, 14, 17, 29, 2, 3, 1, 5, 2, 3, 29, 21, 18, 16, 14, 5))

OLS <- lm(y~ A + time*task, data=df)
```

I'm trying to get a similar result with the `nls` function:

```
NLS <- nls(y ~ A + B*time*task, data=df, start=list(A=1,B=1))

Error in B * time * task : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

It seems I'm not using `nls` the way it should be used, so what is it that am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr** because you can't multiply a factor variable (`task`) by a numeric variable (`time`).

If you want to use `nls` to fit linear models (for whatever reason) you need to replicate the things that `lm()` is doing under the hood. In particular, in R formula language, `time*task` means "effect of time, effect of task, and their interaction". **If** both variables were numeric, then the interaction variable is just the regular product of the two variables, but if at least one is numeric, something more complicated happens. The simplest way to replicate is to use `model.matrix()`:

```r
X <- as.data.frame(model.matrix(~time*task, data =df))
names(X)
## "(Intercept)" "time"        "tasky"       "taskz"       "time:tasky" "time:taskz" 
X$y <- df$y ## add response variable (slight abuse of notation)
```

Because `task` has three levels, we need a total of five derived variables (plus the intercept) to fit the full model.

```r
NLS <- nls(y ~ A + b1*time + b2*tasky + b3*taskz + b4*`time:tasky` + b5*`time:taskz`,
           data=X, start=list(A=1,b1 = 0, b2 = 0, b3 = 0, b4 = 0, b5 = 0))
coef(NLS)
##         A        b1        b2        b3        b4        b5 
## -5.600000  5.171429  6.638095 86.095238 -5.000000 -9.257143
```

Compare with OLS:

```r
OLS <- lm(y~ 1 + time*task, data=df)  ## 'A' doesn't work
coef(OLS)
## (Intercept)        time       tasky       taskz  time:tasky  time:taskz 
##   -5.600000    5.171429    6.638095   86.095238   -5.000000   -9.257143
```

You can also embed a linear submodel in a nonlinear model using the `params` argument of `nlme::gnls`:

```r
GNLS <- nlme::gnls(y ~ mu, data = df, 
                   params = list(mu ~ 1 + time*task),
                   start = list(mu = rep(0,6)))
```

Same coefficients.